# Unable to print variable value inside string using Write-Output

Tags: json, string, powershell

This is how my input string (`$inputStr`) looks like:

```
{
    "CloudId" : "67f8f457-1c4a-4622-a743-638318af04e3",
    "ComputerName" : "Computer1",
    "DeploymentErrorInfo" : {
        "IsConditionallyTerminating" : null,
        "MomAlertSeverity" : null,
        "DisplayableErrorCode" : null,
        "IsSuccess" : null,
        "DetailedCode" : null,
        "IsMomAlert" : null,
        "DetailedSource" : null,
        "CloudProblem" : null,
        "IsTerminating" : null,
        "DetailedErrorCode" : null,
        "ExceptionDetails" : null,
        "Code" : null,
        "ShowDetailedError" : null,
        "RecommendedActionCLI" : null,
        "ErrorCodeString" : null,
        "IsDeploymentBlocker" : null,
        "ErrorType" : null,
        "RecommendedAction" : null,
        "Problem" : null,
        "MessageParameters" : null
    },
    "GrantedToList" : [],
    "ID" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "LocalAdminUserName" : "administrator",
    "Name" : "Computer1",
    "NewVirtualNetworkAdapterInput" : [],
    "OperatingSystemInstance" : {
        "Architecture" : null,
        "Edition" : null,
        "Description" : null,
        "Version" : null,
        "Name" : null,
        "OSType" : null,
        "ProductType" : null
    },
    "Owner" : {
        "UserName" : null,
        "RoleID" : null,
        "RoleName" : null
    },
    "StampId" : "23e6799c-33d4-45ea-8e4f-49ec7d5f26e0",
    "StartVM" : true,
    "VMNetworkAssignments" : [],
    "VMTemplateId" : "fdc73f71-1c6d-4e8f-9d02-21c7f4756c2d"
}
```

I am converting this to an object using `ConvertFrom-Json` command.

```
$paramObject = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $inputStr
```

I want it to print `'VM Computer1 is ready'` but it does not work and it actually prints the whole string:

```
Write-Host "VM $paramObject.Name is ready" # prints the entire thing
Write-Host 'VM $paramObject.Name is ready' # prints command
Write-Host $paramObject.Name # prints VM Name so I know I am able to get the VM Name.
```

Comment: You could have seen the basic problem by looking at the output from that first `Write-Host` command a bit more closely. That is you would have seen `.Name` in the output directly after the closing `}` from the object indicating that the member selection hadn't worked correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using string interpolation, you need to use a [sub-expression `$(...)`](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) whenever you want to access a member of an object:

```powershell
Write-Host "VM $($paramObject.Name) is ready"
```

Otherwise, PowerShell will treat the `.Name` part as just normal text.